# Realización modelo SVR en python

Tags: python

estoy intentando realizar un modelo SVR, pero este puede estar horas procesando y no me da resultado. He llegado a probar 4 horas de procesamiento y sigue sin darme resultado. ¿Alguien sabría ponerle un limite de hora o hacer que me de resultado aunque el resultado no sea tan preciso?

En primer lugar, se ha creado una función para que me devuelva a parte del modelo el resultado de este de precisión:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

def entrenar_modelo(modelo,
                    preprocessor: ColumnTransformer,
                    x_data: pd.DataFrame,
                    y_data: pd.Series,
                    test_frac:float=0.2,
                  ):

    # dividir el dataset en entrenamiento y prueba
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y_data,
                                                        random_state=42,
                                                        test_size=test_frac)
    # crear el pipeline con el preprocesador y el modelo
    regressor_pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("preprocessor", preprocessor),
                                     ("model", modelo)])

    # entrenar el pipeline de regresion
    model = regressor_pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)

    y_pred_train = model.predict(x_train)

    # predecir con el pipeline de regresion
    y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

    train_score = mean_absolute_error(y_train, y_pred_train)
    test_score = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
    R=r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
    print("Entrenamiento_score : " , train_score)
    print("Prueba_score : ", test_score)
    print("R2 : ", R)

    return {
            'Entrenamiento_score': train_score,
            'Prueba_score': test_score,
            'R2':R
           }
```

Y luego este sería el modelo formulado:

```
result_dict['SVR'] = entrenar_modelo(SVR(kernel='linear', epsilon=0.05, C=0.3),
                                     preprocessor,
                                     x_train,
                                     y_train)
```

Si alguien sabe una solución al respecto, ya que aparte de no ser eficiente que tarde tanto es que no me devuelve resultado ni solución del modelo.

Answer (score 0):

quizás ya hayas optado por otra solución. Yo la primera aproximación cuando me pasa eso es que reduzco el volumen de datos de x_train e y_train a 1/10. Si aún así te tarda, sigue reduciéndolo hasta que corra.
Como indicas, así podrías conseguir un resultado aunque sea menos preciso.Y luego sabiendo lo que tarda y la precisión que te da, decide el tamaño del entrenamiento.